# Trying to connect Django dev server from remote

Tags: python, django

I have deployed my django application in server or machine A.
I want to access my web page from machine B. 
My machine B runs in a virtual box and I did a ssh to machine A. 
I started the django development server at machine A using the command:
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
I go to machine B try to access my webpage using:
http://ip-machine-A:8000/appname/login/
However,I'm unable to connect. 
I have been through similar questions and I have tried all the solutions like modifying allowed_hosts in settings.py to ['*']. I also tried to ping the machine A and I got the response. And I also checked if the port is open by issuing the following command and it worked too.
netstat -anp | grep 8000
Is there anything else I should work on to make this work? Or is this issue associated with Django development server.

Comment: wow that is a hard wall of text to read ... are both computers on the same subnet(same router?) ... if both computers are on the same subnet then make sure the ip address looks like `192.168.X.X`(most likely subnet for home router) ... if it is on a different network it gets more complicated

Comment: try generating a private key to acces

Comment: Why are you using the development server for something that is not development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line

```
allowed_hosts=['MY_SERVER_IP']
```

in the file

> /lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py

and when I did

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

it worked.